# Large RegEx Match causing program hang

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, parsing

I tried asking this the other day, and admittedly did not phrase the question well or post code at first, and the answer was closed.  So here I am trying again, because honestly this is driving me insane very quickly.  :)

I am trying to implement this [Address Parser](http://usaddress.codeplex.com/), which is originally a console-based c# program.  I have successfully converted it into a standalone WPF program which consists solely of a `TextBox` for input, a `Button` to activate the parsing, and a `TextBlock` to display the results.  In writing this, I did truncate the output to what I will need in my main program, and still it works fine.  I have included the entire code behind for this below.

My next step was to graft this into my main program, which I did by literally using copy/paste.  Upon running this however, the program hangs after the button press.  Eventually VS gives an error that the process has gone too long without pumping out a message, and the memory usage in TaskManager gradually increases from ~70k to 3,000,000.  In response to this, I assigned the `Parsing` method to a background worker, hoping to alleviate the workload on the main process.  This did solve the program freezing up, but the background thread just did the same thing, raising the RAM usage and returning nothing.

So now I'm kind of at an impasse.  I know that the problem is somewhere in the `var result = parser.ParseAddress(input);` statement, as when using breakpoints for every line of code this is the last one to fire.  But basically I'm at a loss to understand why this would cause a problem in one WPF program and not another.

I would be more than happy to post the full source code for the main program somewhere if it's necessary, but I can't imagine it would be a good idea to post ~20 different class files and projects worth of code here.  :)

**Stand-Alone WPF App**

```
namespace AddressParseWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            AddressParser.AddressParser parser = new AddressParser.AddressParser();
            var input = inputTextBox.Text;

            var result = parser.ParseAddress(input);

            if (result == null)
            {
                outputTextBlock.Text = "ERROR. Input could not be parsed.";
            }
            else
            {
                outputTextBlock.Text = (result.StreetLine + ", " + result.City + ", " + result.State + "  " + result.Zip);
            }
        }

        private void actionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Program to graft Parser into**

```
public void ExecuteAddressParse()
{
    AddressParser.AddressParser parser = new AddressParser.AddressParser();
    var input = inputTextBox.Text;

    var result = parser.ParseAddress(input);

    if (result == null)
    {
        outputTextBlock.Text = "ERROR. Input could not be parsed.";
    }
    else
    {
        outputTextBlock.Text = (result.StreetLine + ", " + result.City + ", " + result.State + "  " + result.Zip);
    }
}       

private void actionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteAddressParse();
}
```

**ParseAddress method**

```
public AddressParseResult ParseAddress(string input)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        var match = addressRegex.Match(input.ToUpperInvariant());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var extracted = GetApplicableFields(match);
            return new AddressParseResult(Normalize(extracted));
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**RegEx Match method**

```
private static void InitializeRegex()
{
    var suffixPattern = new Regex(
        string.Join(
            "|",
            new [] {
                string.Join("|", suffixes.Keys), 
                string.Join("|", suffixes.Values.Distinct())
            }),
        RegexOptions.Compiled);

    var statePattern = 
        @"\b(?:" + 
        string.Join(
            "|",
            new [] {
                string.Join("|", states.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))),
                string.Join("|", states.Values)
            }) +
        @")\b";

    var directionalPattern =
        string.Join(
            "|",
            new [] {
                string.Join("|", directionals.Keys),
                string.Join("|", directionals.Values),
                string.Join("|", directionals.Values.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"(\w)", @"$1\.")))
            });

    var zipPattern = @"\d{5}(?:-?\d{4})?";

    var numberPattern =
        @"(
            ((?<NUMBER>\d+)(?<SECONDARYNUMBER>(-[0-9])|(\-?[A-Z]))(?=\b))    # Unit-attached
            |(?<NUMBER>\d+[\-\ ]?\d+\/\d+)                                   # Fractional
            |(?<NUMBER>\d+-?\d*)                                             # Normal Number
            |(?<NUMBER>[NSWE]\ ?\d+\ ?[NSWE]\ ?\d+)                          # Wisconsin/Illinois
          )";

    var streetPattern =
        string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            @"
                (?:
                  # special case for addresses like 100 South Street
                  (?:(?<STREET>{0})\W+
                     (?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)
                  |
                  (?:(?<PREDIRECTIONAL>{0})\W+)?
                  (?:
                    (?<STREET>[^,]*\d)
                    (?:[^\w,]*(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)
                   |
                    (?<STREET>[^,]+)
                    (?:[^\w,]+(?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)
                    (?:[^\w,]+(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)?
                   |
                    (?<STREET>[^,]+?)
                    (?:[^\w,]+(?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)?
                    (?:[^\w,]+(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)?
                  )
                )
            ",
            directionalPattern,
            suffixPattern);

    var rangedSecondaryUnitPattern =
        @"(?<SECONDARYUNIT>" +
        string.Join("|", rangedSecondaryUnits.Keys) +
        @")(?![a-z])";
    var rangelessSecondaryUnitPattern =
        @"(?<SECONDARYUNIT>" +
        string.Join(
            "|",
            string.Join("|", rangelessSecondaryUnits.Keys)) +
        @")\b";
    var allSecondaryUnitPattern = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"
            (
                (:?
                    (?: (?:{0} \W*)
                        | (?<SECONDARYUNIT>\#)\W*
                    )
                    (?<SECONDARYNUMBER>[\w-]+)
                )
                |{1}
            ),?
        ",
         rangedSecondaryUnitPattern,
         rangelessSecondaryUnitPattern);

    var cityAndStatePattern = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"
            (?:
                (?<CITY>[^\d,]+?)\W+
                (?<STATE>{0})
            )
        ",
        statePattern);
    var placePattern = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"
            (?:{0}\W*)?
            (?:(?<ZIP>{1}))?
        ",
        cityAndStatePattern,
        zipPattern);

    var addressPattern = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"
            ^
            # Special case for APO/FPO/DPO addresses
            (
                [^\w\#]*
                (?<STREETLINE>.+?)
                (?<CITY>[AFD]PO)\W+
                (?<STATE>A[AEP])\W+
                (?<ZIP>{4})
                \W*
            )
            |
            # Special case for PO boxes
            (
                \W*
                (?<STREETLINE>(P[\.\ ]?O[\.\ ]?\ )?BOX\ [0-9]+)\W+
                {3}
                \W*
            )
            |
            (
                [^\w\#]*    # skip non-word chars except # (eg unit)
                (  {0} )\W*
                   {1}\W+
                (?:{2}\W+)?
                   {3}
                \W*         # require on non-word chars at end
            )
            $           # right up to end of string
        ",
        numberPattern,
        streetPattern,
        allSecondaryUnitPattern,
        placePattern,
        zipPattern);
    addressRegex = new Regex(
        addressPattern,
        RegexOptions.Compiled | 
        RegexOptions.Singleline | 
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions with backtracking may be very slow, especially on large inputs. Try limiting the input that you give to the expression to three lines at a time: in the `ParseAddress` method, split text into separate lines, and give it to regexp in a loop, lines {0,1,2}, then {1,2,3}, then {2,3,4} and so on. Return when a match is found.

Comment: Did you by any chance accidentally modify the regular expressions when moving the code over? Or modified the input when copy and pasting it? Did you initialize the parser? Or did you accidentally double-click the button, thus triggering some weird bug in the library? The high memory consumption points to a bad regex/input combination though - bad runtime behavior

Comment: The input is just a simple US address, such as "1234 Main St, Anytown, NY 46521".  As for limiting the input, I don't even know how I could do that given the way the RegEx is written.  Basically he defines a large group of dictionaries, then glues them together to form one massive RegEx that parses the address.  Finally, when moving the code over, I used "Add Existing Project" from VS to import the `Parse` files, and as you can see above the only thing I changed was the name of the method so it would be easier to identify.  As for the input being bad, I actually tried the same address in both.

Comment: I added a sample of the `RegEx` code above, hopefully this might help a bit.  And again, the confusing part is that it works in the simple program, just not the larger one.  And I know for a fact it isn't a naming conflict, and there's nothing intensive going on in the large program either.

Comment: @KevenM: Does the Regex work when omitting the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag?

Comment: @leppie Yes, it does.  You are my hero.  :)  Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can give you credit for it?  And why is that the case, I thought `Compiled` was supposed to make startup slower, but the regex itself run faster?

Comment: Is this going to be on a website? `Compiled` is a good call and should save you significant performance, but when there are a whole bunch of users hitting your server at once, I don't think it's going to be enough.

Comment: No, it's in a self-contained WPF desktop app, no server connections at all.

Comment: Still, if you're hitting this enough to justify spending the time to build it, it's worth looking at the backtracking problem. I see multiple places where this is a potential issue. [Optimizing your engine can only take you so far](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/everything-is-fast-for-small-n.html) before a slow algorithm starts to kill you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the Regex work when omitting the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag?

Reply was yes.

So why?

It seems the Regex compiler is slow with (some?) large patterns.

It's a trade-off you have to make.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again, I have this working now and it's perfect!.  To anyone else that reads this question, please give leppie an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the regex sub-expressions are innapropriate (as @Justin Morgan mentions).
This is usually the result of joining reusable fragmented regex and it makes
me cringe.

But, if your going to use/do this approach, its always a good idea to print out the
actual regex after its constructed. And, after formatting it, test it against
samples and do it independently of your main program. Its easier to fix like that.
Where you see suspect sub-expressions, try to make it fail at that point, or
in general, try to insert failure near the end of the sample. If it takes more than
a blink of an eye to fail, then its severly backtracking.

Backtracking isin't bad though. It's got a huge upside. Without it, some things
just wouldn't match. The trick is to isolate sub-expressions that don't affect
the outcome relative to whats around it, then limit it from bactracking.

I went to the USPS site and grabbed some sample state/suffix/direction/secondary
samples, enough to generate the address regex. Below is a cleaned up version of
the regex generated from your code.

Good Luck!

```
 ^
   # Special case for APO/FPO/DPO addresses
   (
      [^\w\#]*
      (?<STREETLINE> .+? )
      (?<CITY> [AFD] PO )
      \W+
      (?<STATE> A [AEP] )
      \W+
      (?<ZIP> \d{5} (?: -? \d{4} )? )
      \W*
   )
 |         
   # Special case for PO boxes
   (
      \W*
      (?<STREETLINE> ( P [\.\ ]? O [\.\ ]? \  )? BOX \  [0-9]+ )
      \W+
      (?:
          (?:
              (?<CITY> [^\d,]+? )
              \W+
              (?<STATE>
                 \b
                 (?:AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|Alabama|Alaska|American Samoa|Arizona|Arkansas)
                 \b
              )
          )
          \W*
      )?
      (?:
          (?<ZIP> \d{5} (?: -? \d{4} )? )
      )?
      \W*
   )
 |          
   (
       [^\w\#]*    # skip non-word chars except # (eg unit)
       (
         (
              (
                (?<NUMBER> \d+ )
                (?<SECONDARYNUMBER> (-[0-9]) | (\-?[A-Z]) )
                (?=\b)
              )                                                  # Unit-attached
           |          
             (?<NUMBER> \d+ [\-\ ]? \d+ \/ \d+ )                 # Fractional
           |
             (?<NUMBER> \d+ -? \d* )                             # Normal Number
           |
             (?<NUMBER>[NSWE]\ ?\d+\ ?[NSWE]\ ?\d+)              # Wisconsin/Illinois
         )
       )
       \W*

       (?:
           # special case for addresses like 100 South Street
           (?:
               (?<STREET>North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest|N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW|N\.|E\.|S\.|W\.|N\.E\.|S\.E\.|N\.W\.|S\.W\.)
               \W+
               (?<SUFFIX>ALLEY|ALY|ALLY|ALLEE|ALLEY|ALY)
               \b
           )
         |
           (?:
               (?<PREDIRECTIONAL>North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest|N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW|N\.|E\.|S\.|W\.|N\.E\.|S\.E\.|N\.W\.|S\.W\.)
               \W+
           )?
           (?:
                (?<STREET> [^,]* \d )
                (?:
                   [^\w,]*
                   (?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest|N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW|N\.|E\.|S\.|W\.|N\.E\.|S\.E\.|N\.W\.|S\.W\.)
                   \b
                )
             |
                (?<STREET> [^,]+ )
                (?:
                    [^\w,]+
                    (?<SUFFIX>ALLEY|ALY|ALLY|ALLEE|ALLEY|ALY)
                    \b
                )
                (?:
                    [^\w,]+
                    (?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest|N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW|N\.|E\.|S\.|W\.|N\.E\.|S\.E\.|N\.W\.|S\.W\.)
                    \b
                )?
             |
                (?<STREET> [^,]+? )
                (?:
                    [^\w,]+
                    (?<SUFFIX>ALLEY|ALY|ALLY|ALLEE|ALLEY|ALY)
                    \b
                )?
                (?:
                    [^\w,]+
                    (?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>North|East|South|West|Northeast|Southeast|Northwest|Southwest|N|E|S|W|NE|SE|NW|SW|N\.|E\.|S\.|W\.|N\.E\.|S\.E\.|N\.W\.|S\.W\.)
                    \b
                )?
           )
       )           

       \W+        

       (?:      
           (
               (
                  :?
                  (?:
                      (?:
                         (?<SECONDARYUNIT>APT|BLDG|DEPT|FL|HNGR|LOT|PIER|RM|SLIP|SPC|STOP|STE|TRLR|UNIT)
                         (?! [a-z] )
                         \W*
                       )
                    |
                       (?<SECONDARYUNIT> \# )
                       \W*
                  )
                  (?<SECONDARYNUMBER> [\w-]+ )
               )
             |
               (?<SECONDARYUNIT>BSMT|FRNT|LBBY|LOWR|OFC|PH|REAR|SIDE|UPPR)
               \b
           )
           ,?
           \W+
       )?

       (?:
           (?:
               (?<CITY> [^\d,]+? )
               \W+
               (?<STATE>
                  \b
                  (?:AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|Alabama|Alaska|American Samoa|Arizona|Arkansas)
                  \b
               )
           )
           \W*
       )?

       (?:
           (?<ZIP> \d{5} (?: -? \d{4} )? )
       )?

       \W*         # require on non-word chars at end
   )
 $           # right up to end of string
```

C# code

```
   public static void InitializeRegex()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> suffixes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
          {"ALLEY",  "ALLEE"},
          {"ALY",  "ALLEY"},
          {"ALLY",  "ALY"},
        };

        var suffixPattern = new Regex(
            string.Join(
                "|",
                new[] {
            string.Join("|", suffixes.Keys.ToArray()), 
            string.Join("|", suffixes.Values.Distinct().ToArray())
        }),
            RegexOptions.Compiled);

        //Console.WriteLine("\n"+suffixPattern);

        Dictionary<string, string> states = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
           {"AL", "Alabama"},
           {"AK", "Alaska"},
           {"AS",  "American Samoa"},
           {"AZ",  "Arizona"},
           {"AR", "Arkansas"}
        };

        var statePattern =
            @"\b(?:" +
            string.Join(
                "|",
                new[] {
            string.Join("|", states.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x)).ToArray()),
            string.Join("|", states.Values.ToArray())
        }) +
            @")\b";

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + statePattern);

        Dictionary<string, string> directionals = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
           {"North", "N" },
           {"East", "E" },
           {"South", "S" },
           {"West", "W" },
           {"Northeast", "NE" },
           {"Southeast", "SE" },
           {"Northwest", "NW" },
           {"Southwest", "SW" }
        };

        var directionalPattern =
            string.Join(
                "|",
                new[] {
            string.Join("|", directionals.Keys.ToArray()),
            string.Join("|", directionals.Values.ToArray()),
            string.Join("|", directionals.Values.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"(\w)", @"$1\.")).ToArray())
        });

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + directionalPattern);

        var zipPattern = @"\d{5}(?:-?\d{4})?";

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + zipPattern);

        var numberPattern =
            @"(
                ((?<NUMBER>\d+)(?<SECONDARYNUMBER>(-[0-9])|(\-?[A-Z]))(?=\b))    # Unit-attached
                |(?<NUMBER>\d+[\-\ ]?\d+\/\d+)                                   # Fractional
                |(?<NUMBER>\d+-?\d*)                                             # Normal Number
                |(?<NUMBER>[NSWE]\ ?\d+\ ?[NSWE]\ ?\d+)                          # Wisconsin/Illinois
             )";

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + numberPattern);

        var streetPattern =
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                @"
                    (?:
                      # special case for addresses like 100 South Street
                      (?:(?<STREET>{0})\W+
                         (?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)
                      |
                      (?:(?<PREDIRECTIONAL>{0})\W+)?
                      (?:
                        (?<STREET>[^,]*\d)
                        (?:[^\w,]*(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)
                       |
                        (?<STREET>[^,]+)
                        (?:[^\w,]+(?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)
                        (?:[^\w,]+(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)?
                       |
                        (?<STREET>[^,]+?)
                        (?:[^\w,]+(?<SUFFIX>{1})\b)?
                        (?:[^\w,]+(?<POSTDIRECTIONAL>{0})\b)?
                      )
                    )
                ",
                directionalPattern,
                suffixPattern);

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + streetPattern);


        Dictionary<string, string> rangedSecondaryUnits = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"APT",  "APARTMENT"},
            {"BLDG", "BUILDING"}, 
            {"DEPT", "DEPARTMENT"}, 
            {"FL",   "FLOOR"}, 
            {"HNGR", "HANGAR"}, 
            {"LOT",  "LOT"}, 
            {"PIER", "PIER"}, 
            {"RM",   "ROOM"}, 
            {"SLIP", "SLIP"}, 
            {"SPC",  "SPACE"}, 
            {"STOP", "STOP"}, 
            {"STE",  "SUITE"}, 
            {"TRLR", "TRAILER"}, 
            {"UNIT", "UNIT"} 
        };
        var rangedSecondaryUnitPattern =
            @"(?<SECONDARYUNIT>" +
            string.Join("|", rangedSecondaryUnits.Keys.ToArray()) +
            @")(?![a-z])";

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + rangedSecondaryUnitPattern);


        Dictionary<string, string> rangelessSecondaryUnits = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"BSMT", "BASEMENT"},
            {"FRNT", "FRONT"},
            {"LBBY", "LOBBY"},
            {"LOWR", "LOWER"},
            {"OFC",  "OFFICE"},
            {"PH",   "PENTHOUSE"},
            {"REAR", "REAR"},
            {"SIDE", "SIDE"},
            {"UPPR", "UPPER"}
        };

        var rangelessSecondaryUnitPattern =
            @"(?<SECONDARYUNIT>" +
            string.Join("|", rangelessSecondaryUnits.Keys.ToArray()) +
            @")\b";

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + rangelessSecondaryUnitPattern);

        var allSecondaryUnitPattern = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            @"
                (
                    (:?
                        (?: (?:{0} \W*)
                            | (?<SECONDARYUNIT>\#)\W*
                        )
                        (?<SECONDARYNUMBER>[\w-]+)
                    )
                    |{1}
                ),?
            ",
             rangedSecondaryUnitPattern,
             rangelessSecondaryUnitPattern);

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + allSecondaryUnitPattern);

        var cityAndStatePattern = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            @"
                (?:
                    (?<CITY>[^\d,]+?)\W+
                    (?<STATE>{0})
                )
            ",
            statePattern);

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + cityAndStatePattern);

        var placePattern = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            @"
                (?:{0}\W*)?
                (?:(?<ZIP>{1}))?
            ",
            cityAndStatePattern,
            zipPattern);

        //Console.WriteLine("\n" + placePattern);

        var addressPattern = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            @"
                ^
                # Special case for APO/FPO/DPO addresses
                (
                    [^\w\#]*
                    (?<STREETLINE>.+?)
                    (?<CITY>[AFD]PO)\W+
                    (?<STATE>A[AEP])\W+
                    (?<ZIP>{4})
                    \W*
                )
                |
                # Special case for PO boxes
                (
                    \W*
                    (?<STREETLINE>(P[\.\ ]?O[\.\ ]?\ )?BOX\ [0-9]+)\W+
                    {3}
                    \W*
                )
                |
                (
                    [^\w\#]*    # skip non-word chars except # (eg unit)
                    (  {0} )\W*
                       {1}\W+
                    (?:{2}\W+)?
                       {3}
                    \W*         # require on non-word chars at end
                )
                $           # right up to end of string
            ",
            numberPattern,
            streetPattern,
            allSecondaryUnitPattern,
            placePattern,
            zipPattern);

        Console.WriteLine("\n-----------------------------\n\n" + addressPattern);

        var addressRegex = new Regex(
            addressPattern,
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.Singleline |
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradually increasing resource use like this is a smoking gun for [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Basically, if you have something like, say, this part:

```
(?<CITY>[^\d,]+?)\W+
```

...then there will be ambiguity about which piece of the input matches which piece of the pattern. Almost anything that matches `\W` could also match `[^\d,]`. If the input fails to match on the first pass, the engine will go back and try different permutations of those two groups, which chews up resources.

For example, suppose the "city" part of your input has a whole bunch of whitespace after it. A long string of whitespace would match both `[^\d,]+?` and `\W+`, so it's not clear whether the CITY group includes the whitespace. Based on the lazy/greedy behavior of those quantifiers, the engine would *try* to put only the city name into `[^\d,]+?` and all the spaces in `\W+`. Then it would move on and try to match the rest of the input.

If the rest of the input matches on the first try, fine. But if matching fails, it will have to go back and try again, this time with one of the spaces being matched by `[^\d,]+?` and captured as part of your CITY group. When that fails, it'll try again with two of the spaces, and so on.

You usually see this becoming a problem with nested quantifiers, e.g. something like `([ABC]+)*`. I don't see anything in your pattern where that's going on, but I might have missed something in all the `string.Format` calls. My guess is just that it's such a long pattern, and has so many quantifiers and alternators to backtrack over (and so many groups to store), that even a single level of iteration is killing you. I'll bet you get the biggest performance hit with a long input string that matches *most* of the pattern, but fails to match all of it.

Compiling the regex will probably help in this case, and you should do it. But when you have a thousand (or however many) hits on your app at once, I doubt that will cut it. There will also be certain input strings that cause a lot of backtracking and hit you much harder, performance-wise. My biggest suggestion is to find and resolve ambiguities in the pattern.

Find places with a lot of quantifiers like `*` and `+` near each other, and make sure there are clear, non-optional delimiters between them (for example, `\d+-?\d*` from your NUMBER group would perform better as `\d+(-\d*)?`, or better yet `\d+(-\d+)?\b`). Finally, make sure the delimiters can't match the tokens next to them. For a made-up example, something like `\W+\ \W+` would drag on and on if you fed it a long string of whitespace.